# How to get cluster datasotre via VMware perl sdk?

Tags: perl, sdk, vmware

Is it possible to list all datastores' name, Capacity space, dunesId that are related to a cluster using VMware perl sdk in Linux?

I try to use `Vim::find_entity_views` to get `ComputeResource` and know that it has Properties: `datastore, host`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible to get datastore list in a cluster

```
my $cluster_view = Vim::find_entity_view(view_type => 'ClusterComputeResource',
                                            filter => { name => $cluster_name });
########## Error trap: verify if the cluster_view variable was set in the previous command
##########             if it was not set, the Cluster Name is incorrect
if (!$cluster_view) {
   die  "\nERROR: '" . $cluster_name . "' was not found in the VMware Infrastructure\n\n";
}

########## Print the table header
print "\n";
print "|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
print "| VMware Cluster: " . $cluster_view->name . "\n";
print "|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";

########## Get a view of the ESX Hosts in the specified Cluster
my $host_views = Vim::find_entity_views(view_type => 'HostSystem',
                                        begin_entity => $cluster_view);

foreach (@$host_views) {
#       print "\n", $_->name;
        print "\n|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
        print "| Datastore in ESXI Host(s) in " . $_->name . "\n";
        print "|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
        print "\n";
        my $datastores = Vim::get_views(mo_ref_array => $_->datastore);
        foreach(@$datastores) {
                print "\n" . $_->summary->name;
       }
}
```